# GSAP Scrolltrigger not working with multiple triggers

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have multiple triggers each does the following:

1. Show/Removes a canvas
2. Changes the background colour of a section
3. Plays/Pauses video when in view
4. Plays/Pauses CSS animation

The first two work when without the other 2 triggers and I get this error on the play pause video: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')
However, I have followed the GSAP tutorial on this so I can only assume there is a conflict with the previous triggers.

```
  const hideWebGl = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".wriggle-cursor",
    scrub: true,
    start: 'top 100%',
    end: 'top -125%',
      onEnter: () => $('.home #canvas').css('display','block'),
      onLeave: () => $('.home #canvas').css('display','none'),
      onEnterBack: () => $('.home #canvas').css('display','block'),
      onLeaveBack: () => $('.home #canvas').css('display','none'),
  },
});

const projectsBackground = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".projects-section-next .whatwedo",
    scrub: true,
    start: 'top 60%',
    end: 'top -300%',
      onEnter: () => $('.projects-section-next .whatwedo').css('background-color','white'),
      onLeave: () => $('.projects-section-next .whatwedo').css('background-color','transparent'),
      onEnterBack: () => $('.projects-section-next .whatwedo').css('background-color','white'),
      onLeaveBack: () => $('.projects-section-next .whatwedo').css('background-color','transparent'),
  },
});

let allVideoDivs = gsap.utils.toArray('.vid-gsap');

allVideoDivs.forEach((videoDiv, i) => {
  
  let videoElem = videoDiv.querySelector('video')
  
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: videoElem,
    start: 'top 80%',
    end: 'top 20%',
    markers: true,
    onEnter: () => videoElem.play(),
    onEnterBack: () => videoElem.play(),
    onLeave: () => videoElem.pause(),
    onLeaveBack: () => videoElem.pause(),
  });
  
});

let allCssAnimation = gsap.utils.toArray('.ticker-marquee');

allCssAnimation.forEach((cssAnimation, i) => {
  
  let cssElem = cssAnimation.querySelector('video')
  
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger:cssElem,
    start: 'top 80%',
    end: 'top 20%',
    markers: true,
    onEnter: () => cssElem.css('-webkit-animation-play-state','running'),
    onLeave: () => cssElem.css('-webkit-animation-play-state','paused'),
    onEnterBack: () => cssElem.css('-webkit-animation-play-state','running'),
    onLeaveBack: () => cssElem.css('-webkit-animation-play-state','paused'),
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the video play pause section to this, and it fixed it.

```
const videos = gsap.utils.toArray('video')

videos.forEach(function(video, i) {
    
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: video,
    start: 'top center',
    end: 'bottom center',
    onEnter: () => video.play(),
    onEnterBack: () => video.play(),
    onLeave: () => video.pause(),
    onLeaveBack: () => video.pause(),
  });
})
```

Comment: Instead of 4 callbacks, you could use onToggle like: 

onToggle: self => self.isActive ? video.play() : video.pause();